# Simple Do Until Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and have a simple question. Once I understand how to to this loop, I can build on it.

I would like to automate a classification. The data repeats itself in a single column i.e sampleA, sampleA, sampleA, sampleB, sampleB, sampleC, sampleC, sampleC, etc. I would like my macro to identify when the sample name changes between the sample names. So, for example, when the following cell after sampleA turns into sampleB, I would like the macro to understand that there is a change and write a phrase next to this (this will next turn into an equation with the data in the sample's respective rows but baby steps :)  ).

Overall, the macro needs to sense the changes between a column of identical sample names until a new name is reached.

I have been researching solutions and the "do until" loop seems to be the closest solution to what I need. Also, to show that sampleA is not the same as sampleB I used <>.

```
Sub DoUntilStringMacro()

Dim sampleA As String

Dim sampleB As String

Dim sampleC As String

Dim classification As String

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

        If sampleA <> sampleB Then
            classification = "hello"
        ElseIf sampleB <> sampleC Then
            classification = "goodbye"
        ElseIf sampleC <> sampleA Then
            classification = "see you soon"
        End If

        answer = classification
        Cells(classification, "B").Value = answer

    Loop

End Sub
```

**Actual results:** error at   Cells(classification, "B").Value = answer
Something is wrong here. I am trying to display results in column "B".

**Expected results on Excel Worksheet in columns:**

```
Sample:  Classification
sampleA  --
sampleA  --
sampleA  hello
sampleB  --
sampleB  goodbye
sampleC  --
sampleC  --
sampleC  see you soon
```

Comment: Relying on `ActiveCell` can cause issues. Instead of using a `Do Until` loop, perhaps consider [finding the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and then looping from start row to last row.

Comment: `SampleA` etc. are never initialized, and it isn't clear what cell you expect something like `Cells("goodbye","B")` to be since `"goodbye"` is manifestly not a row number.

Comment: Can there be blank cells in the range? And can the classification repeat or must it only occur directly before a change? Does the last value before the end blank constitute a change (appears so...)? Is data guaranteed to be ordered?

Comment: You omitted parts of the code because it's not clear where these `sample` variables come from. If you deal with `ActiveCell`, you need to advance it in a loop - otherwise you're stuck with one and the same cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use formulas and avoid loops:

```
Sub IdentifySampleNameChanges()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ‘ change “Sheet1” to your actual sheet name
          With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
             .Formula = "=IF(A2<>A3,""Hello"","""")"
             .Value = .Value
        End With 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you! To add on to this, how would I apply a formula to all of the sampleA, sampleB, etc values above each hello?

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your _original_ question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you. As for the “formula above each hello” you may want to give more details

Answer (score 1):

1. You declare your `sampleA,B,C` variables but you never set them so you when compare those three variables nothing happens.
2. Inside your loop you never set `ActiveCell` to anything so `ActiveCell` just stays whatever it is. You will loop forever because of this.

Here's a rewrite that isn't really optimized. There are certainly better ways to do this (using a for loop over the `Range("A1:A" & lastFilledRow)` for instance), but I wanted to keep this pretty close to your attempt to see how to solve this the way you were planning as it's certainly viable and reasonable way to do it.

I added a ton of comments to explain what was happening.

```
Sub DoUntilStringMacro()

    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim previousValue As String
    Dim classification As String

    'set the first cell to search and we will iterate
    '   from there
    Dim searchCell As Range
    Set searchCell = Sheet1.Range("A2")

    'Lets also get a counter variable to see how many
    '   times we've found a change...
    Dim changesFound As Integer

    'Loop until the searchCell is empty
    Do Until searchCell.Value = ""


        'set the currentValue
        currentValue = searchCell.Value

        'If the previousValue variable is empty then
        '   this is the first cell we're analyzing
        '   so don't bother running this bit of code
        '   that does the comparison
        If previousValue <> "" Then

            'Compare to what we stored in previousValue
            If currentValue <> previousValue Then
                'We found a change, increment our counter
                changesFound = changesFound + 1

                'and based on that value lets figure out
                '   what to write out
                Select Case changesFound
                    Case 1
                        'This is the first time we hit a
                        '   a change so write out "hello"
                        'BUT!!! we need to write it the
                        '   cell above the current
                        '   searchCell and one column over
                        '   We'll use .Offset() to do that
                        searchCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "Hello"
                    Case 2
                        searchCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "goodbye"
                    Case 3
                        searchCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "see you soon"
                End Select

            End If
        End If

        'So we are going to iterate again, lets capture
        '   the currentValue into the previousValue
        '   variable so we have it to compare on the
        '   the next loop
        previousValue = currentValue

        'Also... we want to make sure that searchCell
        '   is the next cell otherwise we will just
        '   keep testing the same cell over and over
        '   again until excel crashes.
        'Again we'll use `.Offset()` to move to the
        '   next row
        Set searchCell = searchCell.Offset(1)

    Loop

    'Heres the kicker... we needed one more iteration
    '   since we exited when the searchCell was blank... 
    '   so that Case 3 never hit... 
    '   we'll just go ahead and fill that out now
    searchCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "See you soon"

End Sub
```

I've done away with `ActiveCell` since that is not a good idea. `Select`, `Activate`, `ActiveCell` these are all crap shoots in VBA. It's better to say "Explicitly this cell/range is what I want" rather than hoping that the cell you are wanting is currently active.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, JNevill! I like how this script is looking and I am understanding until certain points. My first question is: once we set this counter for every time there is a change, these integers 1, 2, 3, etc will replace column A? Looks like you never set a column for these to go in. My second question is: Could we add on to the next column, C, a formula for only the rows that have an integer? And my third question is: I am getting an error at currentValue=searchCell.Value. Why is this?  Thank you so much!

Comment: 1) We do set a column using that `offset(-1,1)`. That says move up on row from the current cell and over one column. 2) I'm not following you on your use of Column `C`. "Only rows that have an integer" but I don't see any integers in your data or the data we are writing into column `B`. 3) What is the error you are getting? Also, hit the "Debug" button so that line is highlighted and hover over `searchCell.Value` and see what value it's reporting in that cell. That may give some hints (beside the error message, which is even more important)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 1) So `offset(-1,1)` is located in the `changesFound= changesFound + 1` line?  2) Yes, you are right. I meant all rows in column B that now have a string, hello, goodbye, etc, and for the script to recognize that there is a string there and to apply a formula to those strings to show in column C. 3) The error states that there is a problem with the range.

Comment: `changesFound` is just a variable that we increment. The value for that variable is held only in that variable and we never write it out anwhere. We do, however, by the use of the `SELECT CASE` statement write out a string to Column B through the use of `Offset(1, -1).value = "somestring"`. I suppose you can put whatever you like in Column C. If you want to do it in VBA you could just add `searchCell.Offset(-1, 2).value = "This is column C, and column B is currently populated!"`. Still not sure on that error. Is there an error number associated to it?

Comment: Okay, I see.  We can insert `Offset(1,-1).value= "somestring"` after the Do Until statement? Same with the one controlling column C? Looks like the exact Run-time error is : ' -2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed and it points to `currentValue=searchCell.Value`

Comment: I found out my mistake for the error. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try For loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Change()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, Row As Long
    Dim PreviousString As String, CurrenctString As String

    'With statement refers to shee 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find last row in Sheet 1 - Column A
         Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop each row start from 3 to lastrow
        For Row = 3 To Lastrow
            PreviousString = .Range("A" & Row - 1).Value
            CurrenctString = .Range("A" & Row).Value

            'Check if both strings are not the same
            If PreviousString <> CurrenctString Then
                If PreviousString = "sampleA" And CurrenctString = "sampleB" Then
                    .Range("B" & Row - 1).Value = "hello"
                ElseIf PreviousString = "sampleB" And CurrenctString = "sampleC" Then
                    .Range("B" & Row - 1).Value = "goodbye"
                ElseIf PreviousString = "sampleC" And CurrenctString = "sampleD" Then
                    .Range("B" & Row - 1).Value = "see you soon"
                End If

            End If

        Next Row

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Error 1004! This worked really well and I learned from the structure of this script. I have two questions about how to modify it. Now, instead of being very specific and naming sampleA, sampleB, etc., how can I tell the script to just read column A as a string? Is there a way I can just call these strings "sampleX" so that I can go all the way down a huge worksheet without specifying? With this, can I loop all the way until the end of the worksheet to say "hello", for example, every time there is a different string? Thank you thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that a help! Yes , you can do by loop each line and change "PreviousString = .Range("A" & Row - 1).Value" to "sampleX=.Range("A" & Row - i).Value" and play around with the code. Give it a try and let me know if you need more help.